# Which algorithm is the best voting method ?

Tags: ranking, voting-system

There are several voting methods such as Borda count, PLurality, BeatPath, Condorcet. Which one the the most accurate method ?

Comment: Define "most accurate?"

Comment: 1. This appears to be off topic; If you feel otherwise, please clarify how it relates to our [list of topics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). 2. Even if it were on-topic, you'd have to be more specific about what you mean by "best" and "most accurate", since no voting system has all the properties we'd like it to have. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbard%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_theorem